# 'Between' with 'to' or 'and' for specifying ranges

Tags: prepositions

I know that normally 'between' is used with 'and'. Howvever, I am not sure if this is still correct, if I want to specify a ranges. Here is an example:

"Method B leads to improvements of between 0.8% **to** 13.3% regarding the costs."

Is the 'to' correct here? When I use 'and' I somehow have the impression that the reader might think that this is not a range but two discrete numbers (so either 0.8% or 13.3%). I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: No, they should not think that. It's _from 1 to 10_ or _between 1 and 10_.

Comment: Thanks Kate Buting for your answer. So you would say that 'to' is wrong in this context, right and you advice me to use 'and'?

Comment: I told you the two correct versions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Kate.